# flutter: File download from server

Tags: flutter

I am downloading file from server but I don't know what happened so, kindly tell me how to solve this issue?

```
await Dio().post("https://test.blockchainhuissieray.com/api/download_file.php", data: {
          "jwt" : token,
          "fileID" : id,
          "directory" : widget.folderName
        },
            options: Options(
                contentType: ContentType.parse("application/json")
            )).then((res) => res.data).then((data) async{
              var intList = data.toString().codeUnits;
              print('File : $intList');
              print(data);
              var filePath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: Uint8List.fromList(intList));
              print(filePath);
              var savedFile = File.fromUri(Uri.file(filePath));
              setState(() {
                _imageFile = Future<File>.sync(() => savedFile);
                images.add(File(data));
                imagel = File(data);
              });
        }).catchError((err){print(err);});

      print(images);
      setState(() {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context){
              return AlertDialog(
                content: Center(
                  child: Image.file(imagel,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      });
```

I/flutter ( 6918): File : [65533, 65533, 65533, 65533, 2, 118, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 8, 1, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 110, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 65533, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 65533, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 65533, 105, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 65533, 65533, 37, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 65533, 1, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 65533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 110, 100, 114, 111, 105, 100, 32, 83, 68, 75, 32, 98, 117, 105, 108, 116, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 120, 56, 54, 0, 50, 48, 49, 57, 58, 48, 53, 58, 49, 55, 32, 49, 48, 58, 52, 54, 58, 48, 53, 0, 71, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 0, 0, 16, 65533, 65533, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 105, 65533, 65533, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 113, 65533, 65533, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 52, 50, 54, 0, 65533, 65533, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 52, 50, 54, 0, 65533, 65533, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 52, 50, 54, 0, 65533, 10, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 121, 65533, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65533, 39, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
I/flutter ( 6918): ����vExif
V/MediaStore( 6918): Create the thumbnail in memory: origId=266, kind=1, isVideo=false
D/skia    ( 6918): --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
I/chatty  ( 6918): uid=10087(io.hexasoft.bch) identical 1 line
D/skia    ( 6918): --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
I/flutter ( 6918): saved filePath:
I/flutter ( 6918): 
I/flutter ( 6918): [File: '����vExif

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package instead of the ImagePicker plugin. Then write those raw bytes to a file in the temporary directory. Use the file path you generated from there and display the image that way. Or, if you don't need to save the image to the local storage you could display the image with the raw bytearray by using `Image.memory` instead of `Image.file`